# repeat method while answer yes

Tags: java, arrays, object, repeat, do-while

```
package homework4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog4 {
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{   CreditCardNumber[] cred1;
    CreditCardNumber cred2 = getInput();
    Display("The complete number from your input:", cred2);
    cred1 = getInputArray();
    DisplayArray(cred1);
    TryAnother(cred1);
}

public static CreditCardNumber getInput() {
    String ID;
    String accNum;
    CreditCardNumber tempCred;      
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    ID = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Please enter account number:");
    accNum = scanner.next();
    tempCred = new CreditCardNumber(ID, accNum);

    return tempCred;
}
public static void Display(String ch, CreditCardNumber cred2)
{

    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println(cred2.toString().replaceAll(".{4}", "$0   "));       
}

public static CreditCardNumber[] getInputArray()
{
    CreditCardNumber[] tempArray;
    String tempID;
    int size;       
    System.out.printf("Please enter size of the aray:");
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    if(size < 1)
    {
        size = 1;
    }
    tempArray = new CreditCardNumber[size];
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    tempID = scanner.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = new CreditCardNumber();
        tempArray[i].CreateCred(tempID);
    }

    return tempArray;
}

public static void DisplayArray(CreditCardNumber[] cred1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< cred1.length; i++)
    {
        Display("Credit Card # " + i+":" + '\n', cred1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean TryAnother(CreditCardNumber[] cred1)   // pass cred1 as a parameter
{
    String s;
    System.out.printf("Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):");
    s = scanner.next();
    if(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n')
    {

        do
        {
            TryAnother(cred1);
            cred1 = getInputArray();
            DisplayArray(cred1);                
        }while(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n');       
    }
    return false;   // put the return statement here
}
}
```

Hi I'm trying to repeat from the getInputArray method in my TryAnother method,  I try this with the do-while loop  but it said cred1 is undefined inside the do while loop but when i try to create a local object for cred1 it gave me the error code unreachable 
This what the output should look like if the do-while loop work

```
Enter a credit card issuer number: 321321
Enter an account number: 654654654
The complete number from your input: 
3213 2165 4654 6549

Enter the number of elements in the array: 7
Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 789789

Credit Card # 0: 
7897 8931 4062 1219

Credit Card # 1: 
7897 8920 2125 3522

Credit Card # 2: 
7897 8971 9793 0944

Credit Card # 3: 
7897 8979 3216 3090

Credit Card # 4: 
7897 8995 0461 8493

Credit Card # 5: 
7897 8948 8037 5909

Credit Card # 6: 
7897 8966 0251 9953

Get more credit card numbers? (n for no): ok

Enter the number of elements in the array: 3
Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 345345

Credit Card # 0: 
3453 4576 6705 1666

Credit Card # 1: 
3453 4548 1163 5684

Credit Card # 2: 
3453 4563 8807 0419
```

Get more credit card numbers? (n for no): sure

can anyone suggest a way to do the do-while loop ?
thank you in advance

i have edited the code now that it  is doing the repeat part for some reason when i enter no the process does not terminate

something like:

Please enter issuer ID:321321
Please enter account number:654654654
The complete number from your input:
3213   2165   4654   6549
Please enter size of the aray:7
Please enter issuer ID:789789
Credit Card # 0:

7897   8985   6852   9257
Credit Card # 1:

7897   8917   0678   9958
Credit Card # 2:

7897   8900   5781   0934
Credit Card # 3:

7897   8949   2244   6098
Credit Card # 4:

7897   8941   3828   4895
Credit Card # 5:

7897   8965   9233   5006
Credit Card # 6:

7897   8981   8442   5880

```
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):n
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):n
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):no
Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):
```

as you can see when I enter no it keep repeat the same sentence what i want is for it to repeat from enter the array size sentence 
how can i do this?

Comment: `System.out.printf` doesn't this throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you expecting as the output of this program. Since you asked about a compile error, I have edited your code and removed two compile errors.

1. `cred1` is not defined in the `TryAnother()`. Hence you have to pass it as a parameter. Like this `TryAnother(CreditCardNumber[] cred1)`
2. In the `TryAnother()` method, you have put a `return true` statement in side a if block, but before a do-while loop. This will gives you a unreachable statement compile error, since there is no further execution after executing a `return` statement in a method. So you have to put the `return true` statement after the do-while loop.

Here is the corrected code.
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog4 {`

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{   CreditCardNumber[] cred1;
    CreditCardNumber cred2 = getInput();
    Display("The complete number from your input:", cred2);
    cred1 = getInputArray();
    DisplayArray(cred1);
    TryAnother(cred1);         // pass variable cred1 as a parameter
}

public static CreditCardNumber getInput() {
    String ID;
    String accNum;
    CreditCardNumber tempCred;
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    ID = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Please enter account number:");
    accNum = scanner.next();
    tempCred = new CreditCardNumber(ID, accNum);
    return tempCred;
}

public static void Display(String ch, CreditCardNumber cred2)
{
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println(cred2.toString().replaceAll(".{4}", "$0   "));
}

public static CreditCardNumber[] getInputArray()
{
    CreditCardNumber[] tempArray;
    String tempID;
    int size;
    System.out.printf("Please enter size of the aray:");
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    if(size < 1)
    {
        size = 1;
    }
    tempArray = new CreditCardNumber[size];
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    tempID = scanner.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = new CreditCardNumber();
        tempArray[i].CreateCred(tempID);
    }
    return tempArray;
}

public static void DisplayArray(CreditCardNumber[] cred1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< cred1.length; i++)
    {
        Display("Credit Card # " + i+":" + '\n', cred1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean TryAnother(CreditCardNumber[] cred1)   // pass cred1 as a parameter
{
    String s;
    System.out.printf("Get more credit card numbers? (n for no):");
    s = scanner.next();
    if(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n')
    {
        do
        {
            cred1 = getInputArray();
        }while(s.charAt(0) != 'N' || s.charAt(0) != 'n');
    }
    return false;   // put the return statement here
}

}

// A dummy class
class CreditCardNumber{
  String ID;
  String accNum;
  public CreditCardNumber(){
  }
  public CreditCardNumber(String ID,String accNum){
    this.ID = ID;
    this.accNum = accNum;
  }
  public void CreateCred(String tempID){
    ID = tempID;
  }
}

Comment: hi, what happen if i want the tryAnother method itself to repeat ? I try to put the calling statement of TryAnother inside the do-while loop as well and it would not end the process when i answer no

Comment: There are two methods to repeat  tryAnother method. First is recursion and second is calling tryAnother method inside a loop in an another method. I see that you have accepted my answer, thank you very much. But I edited my answer and I'm not sure you accepted the original one or the updated one. I added the 'return true' statement because I forgot it. What version did you accept?

Comment: the original one I also made some changes to it thank you for helping

Comment: You are welcome. I reverted changes and now the original answer is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `cred1` as a global static method, outside of the `main` routine.

Or pass `cred1`, as a parameter to `getInputArray(...)`, which in turn pass them further, to `TryAnother(...)`.

Comment: I cant do that cause it was specified in the assignment that the only class scope variable is the Scanner object for System.in, otherwise I would have done that